# Custom popup / Sitecore client

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, commands

I've requirements to create a custom popup, everytime the author saves an item. The popup has text and two buttons Proceed or Cancel.

Any guidelines on how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same requirement to create a custom popup on the Sitecore client that looks like this

[image]

and here are some general steps you need to follow.

1. Go to core database and open this path. `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks`
2. Using insert from template, Create new chunk item (template path : `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Chunk`)
3. Using insert from template, on this chunk, create a Large Button (template path: `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Large Button`) and enter details.
4. Go to the path (`/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Strips`). Expand this item and you will see name of existing menus. Choose any one where you want to add this button. In this example I am adding under home item.
5. Add a new item using the template (i.e. `/sitecore/templates/System/Reference`)
6. On the publish folder go to the path (`\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs`). Create a folder (I have named it “CustomUrl”) and create a file called (`CustomUrl.xml`). The file is will look like this.

   ```
        <Script>
        function generateUrl()
        {
           var textFrom = document.getElementById("TextFrom").value;
           var textTo = document.getElementById("TextTo").value;
           var textDestination = document.getElementById("TextDestination").value;
           var url = "?fromtext=" + textFrom + "&totext=" + textTo + "&destination=" + textDestination;
           var textUrl = document.getElementById("TextUrl");
           textUrl.innerText = url;
        }
         </Script>
         <style>
         .scFormDialogFooter{
         display: none !important; 
         }
       .scFormDialogFooter .footerOkCancel{
         display: none !important; 
       }        
     </style>

        <div class="scStretch" >
           <div class="col2">
              <Border Background="transparent" Border="none" GridPanel.VAlign="top" Padding="4px 0px 0px 0px">
                 <GridPanel Class="scFormTable" CellPadding="2" Columns="2" Width="100%" GridPanel.Height="100%">
                       <Label For="TextFrom" GridPanel.NoWrap="true">
                       <Literal Text="From Text:" />
                    </Label>
                    <Edit ID="TextFrom" Width="100%" OnChange="generateUrl()"/>
                    <Label for="TextTo" GridPanel.NoWrap="true">
                       <Literal Text="To Text:" />
                    </Label>
                    <Edit ID="TextTo" Width="100%" OnChange="generateUrl()"/>
                    <Label for="TextDestination" GridPanel.NoWrap="true">
                       <Literal Text="Destination Link:" />
                    </Label>
                    <Edit ID="TextDestination" Width="100%" OnChange="generateUrl()"/>

                    <Label for="TextUrl" GridPanel.NoWrap="true">
                       <Literal Text="Copy Url:" />
                    </Label>
                    <Label ID="TextUrl" GridPanel.NoWrap="true">
                    </Label>
                 </GridPanel>
              </Border>
           </div>
        </div>
     </FormDialog>
   ```
7. Add the code file.

```
using System;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;
using Sitecore.Text;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer;
 
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class CustomUrl: Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command
    {
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", context.Parameters);
        }
 
        protected static void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (!args.IsPostBack)
            {
                UrlString urlString = new UrlString(UIUtil.GetUri("control:CustomUrl"));
                SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlString.ToString(), "800", "300", "", true);
                args.WaitForPostBack();
            }
            else
            {
                if (args.HasResult)
                {
                    if (Sitecore.Context.Item.Name == "Content Editor")
                    {
                        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add an entry of this new command in the config.

You may refer to my blog for all the details with a graphical representation of this.

https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2019/07/07/custom-sitecore-menu-button-with-custom-popup-dialog/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, the challenge here, if I want to use buttons in this dialog, let's say "proceed" or "cancel" how I would handle this in the code, I can add the buttons that is fine, but I just don't know how to send the buttons events to the "Run" Processor again, e.g. i clicked proceed this request should be send back from my dialog to the processor again.

Comment: @Jose I think you should try running the pipeline in the execute method that I have mentioned in the answer. See this one for more details. https://archive.doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/def/v1.2/remote-sdk/implementing-a-remote-client/run-pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a custom event within `item:saving` event, invoking a dialog processor in the client pipeline, and pass it a set of arguments.

**Create a custom event handler**

```
public class SaveConfirmPopup
{
    private void StartDialog()
    {
        var savedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

        if (savedItem == null || savedItem.Database.Name.ToLower() != "master")
        {
            return;
        }

        // Start the dialog and pass in an item ID as an argument
        ClientPipelineArgs cpa = new ClientPipelineArgs();
        cpa.Parameters.Add("id", Item.ID.ToString());

        // Kick off the processor in the client pipeline
        Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", cpa);
    }

    protected void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        var id = args.Parameters["id"];

        if (!args.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Show the modal dialog if it is not a post back
            SheerResponse.YesNoCancel("Are you sure you want to do this?", "300px", "100px");

            // Suspend the pipeline to wait for a postback and resume from another processor
            args.WaitForPostBack(true);
        }
        else
        {
            // The result of a dialog is handled because a post back has occurred
            switch (args.Result)
            {
                case "yes":

                    var item = Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(new ID(id));
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        // TODO: act on the item

                        // Reload content editor with this item selected...
                        var load = String.Format("item:load(id={0})", item.ID);
                        Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, load);
                    }

                    break;

                case "no":

                    // TODO: cancel ItemSavingEventArgs

                    break;

                case "cancel":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Create a config patch file**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:saving">
        <handler type="Custom.Events.SaveConfirmPopup, Custom" method="StartDialog"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Reference: [How to display a popup when saving a Sitecore item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322428/how-to-display-a-popup-when-saving-a-sitecore-item)

Hope it helps!